# Make contents of div scroll down with overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a small chat system for a project I am making. The chat is functioning well. However, I cannot figure out how to make it so the div stays at the bottom of the chat, rather than having to scroll down to read the last thing someone said.

I am referring to another similar question posted on here for guidance. [How to keep a div scrolled to the bottom as HTML content is appended to it via jquery, but hide the scroll bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688656/how-to-keep-a-div-scrolled-to-the-bottom-as-html-content-is-appended-to-it-via-j)

But it still will not work for me. The chat is then stored in a chat.txt file. Each line is surrounded in  tags.  The following is the code I am using.

js in header:

```
$container = $('#chat-area');
$container[0].scrollTop = $container[0].scrollHeight;

$('#sendie').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $container = $('#chat-area');
    $container.append('<p>' + e.target.value + '</p>');
    $container.animate({ scrollTop: $container[0].scrollHeight }, "slow");
  }
});
```

chat.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    // strip tags
    name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

    // display name on page
    $("#name-area").html("You are: <span>" + name + "</span>");

    // kick off chat
    var chat =  new Chat();
    $(function() {

         chat.getState(); 

         // watch textarea for key presses
         $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {  

             var key = event.which;  

             //all keys including return.  
             if (key >= 33) {

                 var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                 var length = this.value.length;  

                 // don't allow new content if length is maxed out
                 if (length >= maxLength) {  
                     event.preventDefault();  
                 }  
              }  
                                                                                                                                                                                                        });
         // watch textarea for release of key press
         $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {   

              if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

                var text = $(this).val();
                var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                var length = text.length; 

                // send 
                if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 

                    chat.send(text, name);  
                    $(this).val("");

                } else {

                    $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));

                }   


              }
         });

    });
</script>

<p id="name-area"></p>
    <div id="chatWrap"><div id="chat-area"></div></div>

    <form id="send-message-area">
        <p>Your message: </p>
        <textarea id="sendie" maxlength = '100' ></textarea>
   </form>

</div>
```

css:

```
#pageWrap
{

    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #8B1918;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #333;
    transition: height .5s;
}

#pageWrap p
{
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#chatWrap
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #333 inset;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#chat-area
{
    padding-left: 11px;
}

#sendie
{
    resize: none;
    display: block;
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Still unanswered, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I got it (partially) working for you. Here are the issues I discovered:

- Try not to name variables starting with `$` - it creates unnecessary confusion.
- You didn't declare `$container` as `var`, so you're using a variable before declaring it.
- jQuery supports 99% of everything you can do with plain Javascript, but makes it better. Wherever possible, I changed your code to use jQuery instead.
- I'm not sure about `e.target.value`, but `$('#sendie').val()` works just as well.
- You definitely needed to wrap this in the body onload function.
- You want to add `e.preventDefault();` in the event handler so that it doesn't put a return character in the box.
- You didn't clear the input textarea (with jQuery it's just `$('#sendie').val('');`).
- The font color of the chat message area was white (at least on JSFiddle it was). Messages were invisible due to this.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating everything working (as far as I know) - http://jsfiddle.net/U9XAv/

And here's the updated Javascript:

```
$(function()
{
    var container = $('#chat-area');
    container.css('scrollTop', container.css('scrollHeight'));

    $('#sendie').keydown(function (e)
    {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            container.append('<p>' + $(this).val() + '</p>')
                     .animate({ scrollTop: container[0].scrollHeight) }, "slow");
            $(this).val('');
            e.preventDefault();      
        }
    });
});
```

And the CSS I changed:

```
#chat-area
{
    padding-left: 11px;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this and it still did not work. Not only was it not working, but it then duplicated each entry into the chat.

Comment: Hang on - there's a lot of issues with your code. I'm typing up another response now. I got it to work.

Comment: SpikeX, thank you very much for pointing out the issues in this code. However, in that fiddle, it still isn't scrolling down with the text.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, it should work with the edit I just made. I'm not sure why it's not scrolling.

Comment: Hey no problem, thank you very much for trying. Hopefully this post will get some more answers.

Comment: Some developers prefix variable names for jQuery object variables with the dollar sign to distinguish them from native DOM objects - I personally feel this makes a lot of sense providing the pattern is understood and followed by all devs working on a project. Use jQuery where it makes sense because of differing APIs or incomplete native support, raw JavaScript otherwise - I see an over-reliance on jQuery and plugins to replace widely supported native JavaScript APIs. Abstracting code is never going to make it faster.